# How to use Dependency Injection correctly for a constructor class with parameters in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have a `UserRepository class` that has a `constructor` with several `parameters`, including `EshopContext`, `IValidateIdService`, `ICheckNull`, and `ILogger`. I use this class in the `UserController` class, where I register `dependencies` in the service container (Dependency Injection container) for `IRepository<User>` and `UserRepository`.

The problem is that `Dependency Injection` doesn't seem to work as I would expect, and even though I have registered the services in the container, I still get an error forcing me to pass parameters to the `UserRepository` constructor in the `UserController` class.

What is the correct way to use Dependency Injection so that my service container automatically injects dependencies into the constructor of the `UserRepository` class? What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

**UserRepository.cs**

```
private readonly EshopContext _context;
private readonly IValidateIdService _validateId;
private readonly ICheckNull _checkNull;
private readonly ILogger<UserRepository> _logger;

public UserRepository(
    EshopContext context,
    IValidateIdService validateId,
    ICheckNull checkNull,
    ILogger<UserRepository> logger)
{
    _context = context;
    _validateId = validateId;
    _checkNull = checkNull;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

**UserController.cs**

```
private readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;

public UserController(IRepository<User> userRepository)
{
    _userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IValidateIdService, ValidateIdService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICheckNull, CheckForNullService>();
```

Comment: You need to register `UserRepository` as `IRepository<User>` as well.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you register all of your constructor dependencies that are required by your UserRepository *first,* the DI container should do the right thing.

Comment: I think @JohnathanBarclay does the thing. How do you mean it? I have to only register `            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRepository<User>, UserRepository>();
` and not other dependencies?

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor You need to register _all_ dependencies. The DI container needs to know the concrete type to inject for each dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are 90% there, just register the rest of your dependencies in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IValidateIdService, ValidateIdService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICheckNull, CheckForNullService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<EshopContext, [IMPLEMENTATION]; 
// the comment by @Steven is important to consider, please see my edit below
```

For `ILogger<UserRepository>` you need to have added logging to your services. I'm assuming you already have the nuget package installed and set up.

And that's it. DI "automagically" resolves any dependencies using the services you registered during start up.

**EDIT:**

this is @Steven's comment, adding it to answer for completeness.

The EshopContext is likely an Entity Framework `DbContext` class. If so, it should not be registered as `Singleton` but most likely as `Scoped`. With the built-in DI Container, an extension method exists called `AddDbContext<T>` that allows registering it, as in: `Services.AddDbContex<EshopContext>(...)`

Comment: The `EshopContext` is likely an Entity Framework `DbContext` class. If so, it should not be registered as `Singleton` but most likely as `Scoped`. With the built-in DI Container, an extension method exists called `AddDbContext<T>` that allows registering it, as in: `Services.AddDbContex<EshopContext>(...)`.

Comment: thanks @Steven, I added your comment to the answer